# Using UseHostCompilerIfAvailable=false makes VS to build already built projects over and over again

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have recently learned of the `UseHostCompilerIfAvailable` option. I have set it to `false` hoping it will stop intermittent build failures on VS part (which never occur when building with msbuild on the command line).

Well, builds do not fail, but now VS seems to completely ignore inter project dependencies. Meaning it always builds. Hitting the build button twice performs the same build over and over again.

Does anyone know how to use this option correctly?

Thanks.